# Can't run Realm Studio on Ubuntu 18.10 64 bit (segmentation fault (core dumped))

Tags: linux, ubuntu, realm

I've downloaded Realm Studio from [here](https://studio-releases.realm.io/v2.9.0). When I opened for the first time it asked me if I wanted to integrate it into my system. I clicked on Yes and from there nothing. I can't open the App and if I launch it from terminal I see only

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This happens also with version 2.8 and with the .tar version (Nothing happens if I click on the icon in the extracted archive and the same message if I try to run it from the terminal).

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 64bit. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: ok but is it 64-bit ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, i'll update the question. Thanks.